# Delete every post made in the latest X days in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cron

I was wondering if someone of you guys have implemented such a script in PHP or mysql that runs though a cronjob.

I want to delete every post that is made within the last days with a simple command.
I was wondering if

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

gonna work there. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Your one line of MySQL isn't enough. To fully remove a post, you need to also delete the following:

- relevant post meta data from `wp_postmeta` table
- comments from `wp_comments` table
- metadata in `wp_commentmeta` table for those comments

In terms of providing an actual solution, the following plugins do what you need:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-prune-posts/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/

Also, if you are simply trying to keep your database tidy you can add this line of code to your `wp-config.php` file `define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 8 );` This stops WordPress from creating infinite numbers of post revisions in the database. Not your stated problem but handy.